# Is there a way to direct authenticate mobile apps via keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, mobile-application

I want to integrate mobile application direct authentication via the keycloak. So the users should be able to login via keycloak and use the mobile app. Authentication should be able to done directly other than keycloak REST API.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can using the authorization code flow to secure your application
docs: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#openid-connect